# Error 9: Subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel, range

I have a problem in excel Vba when I try to run this code, I have an error of subscript out of range:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  n_users = Worksheets(Aux).Range("C1").Value

  Debug.Print Worksheets(Aux).Range("B1:B" & n_users).Value

  ListBox1.RowSource = Worksheets(Aux).Range("B1:B" & n_users).Value

  ComboBox1.RowSource = Worksheets(Aux).Range("B1:B" & n_users).Value
  ComboBox2.RowSource = Worksheets(Aux).Range("B1:B" & n_users).Value

End Sub
```

And Debug.Print works well, so the only problem is in Range("B1:B" & n_users).Value.

Comment: Where is aux defined??

Comment: If `Aux` does not refer to an open workbook, or `C1` is 0 you will get this error

Comment: I guess you want `Worksheets("Aux")` instead of `Worksheets(Aux)`?

Comment: - 1 For ignoring the 3 comments on top. I see you have commented in one of the answers below. If you do not want any help then why post a question?

Comment: @SiddharthRout perhaps Aux is defined somewhere else. It is a userform module so maybe its a public variable? But then again, the error caused by attempting to use `Range.Value` to assign a `RowSource` property would not be a `subscript out of range` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, unless you have `Aux` defined somewhere in the actual code, this will not work. The sheet-name reference must be a string value, not an empty variable (which ARich explains in his answer).

Second, the way in which you are trying to populate the rowsource value is incorrect. The rowsource property of a combobox is set using a string value that references the target range. By this I mean the same string value you would use in an excel formula to reference a cell in another sheet. For instance, if your worksheet is named "Aux" then this would be your code:

```
ComboBox1.RowSource = "Aux!B1:B" & n_users
```

I think you can also use named ranges. **[This link](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=59931)** explains it a little.

Comment: If I put ComboBox1.RowSource = "Aux!B1:B17" it works, but in that way doen't work, I don't undertand why.

Comment: Before you use `n_users` as a variable, add `Dim n_users as Integer` (if you haven't already done this).

Answer (score 1):

If the name of your sheet is "Aux", change each `Worksheets(Aux)` reference to `Worksheets("Aux")`. Unless you make `Aux` a string variable, for example:

```
Dim Aux As String  
Aux = "YourWorksheetName"
n_users = Worksheets(Aux).Range(C1).Value
```

you must use quatations around sheet references.

Comment: The problem isn't in worksheet, the problem is in Range("B1:B" & n_users).Value

Answer (score -1):

I can't see how you can get an Error 9 on that line. As others have pointed out repeatedly, the place you'll get it is if the variable Aux doesn't have a string value representing the name of a worksheet. That aside, I'm afraid that there is a LOT wrong with that code. See the comments in the below revision of it, which as near as I can figure is what you're trying to get to:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  'See below re this.
  aux = "Sheet2"

  'You should always use error handling.
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

  'As others have pointed out, THIS is where you'll get a
  'subscript out of range if you don't have "aux" defined previously.
  'I'm also not a fan of NOT using Option Explicit, which
  'would force you to declare exactly what n_users is.
  '(And if you DO have it declared elsewhere, I'm not a fan of using
  'public variables when module level ones will do, or module
  'level ones when local will do.)

  n_users = Worksheets(aux).Range("C1").Value

  'Now, I would assume that C1 contains a value giving the number of
  'rows in the range in column B. However this:

  '*****Debug.Print Worksheets(aux).Range("B1:B" & n_users).Value
   'will only work for the unique case where that value is 1.
   'Why? Because CELLS have values. Multi-cell ranges, as a whole,
   'do not have single values. So let's get rid of that.

  'Have you consulted the online Help (woeful though
  'it is in current versions) about what the RowSource property
  'actually accepts? It is a STRING, which should be the address
  'of the relevant range. So again, unless
  'Range("B1:B" & n_users) is a SINGLE CELL that contains such a string
  '(in which case there's no point having n_users as a variable)
  'this will fail as well when you get to it. Let's get rid of it.
  '****ListBox1.RowSource = Worksheets(aux).Range("B1:B" & n_users).Value

  'I presume that this is just playing around so we'll
  'ignore these for the moment.
  'ComboBox1.RowSource = Worksheets(aux).Range("B1:B" & n_users).Value
  'ComboBox2.RowSource = Worksheets(aux).Range("B1:B" & n_users).Value

  'This should get you what you want. I'm assigning to
  'variables just for clarity; you can skip that if you want.

    Dim l_UsersValue As Long
    Dim s_Address As String
    l_UsersValue = 0
    s_Address = ""

    'Try to get the n_users value and test for validity
    On Error Resume Next
    l_UsersValue = Worksheets(aux).Range("C1").Value
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    l_UsersValue = CLng(l_UsersValue)

    If l_UsersValue < 1 Or l_UsersValue > Worksheets(aux).Rows.Count Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 20000, , "User number range is outside acceptable boundaries. " _
        & "It must be from 1 to the number of rows on the sheet."
    End If

    'Returns the cell address
    s_Address = Worksheets(aux).Range("B1:B" & n_users).Address

    'Add the sheet name to qualify the range address
    s_Address = aux & "!" & s_Address

    'And now that we have a string representing the address, we can assign it.

    ListBox1.RowSource = s_Address

ExitPoint:

   Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description

Resume ExitPoint

End Sub
```

Comment: So someone apparently has a problem with this answer and hit it with a downvote. That's fine, you're entitled to your opinion, which thankfully apparently costs you as many rep points as it cost me. I'm entitled to value your opinion accordingly given that you haven't found it necessary to share your infinitely superior wisdom on exactly what your problem with it IS or, better yet, to offer something better.

Comment: -1 Sorry about that. I marked it down because you essentially rewrote Arich and my answers (albeit with a lot of unnecessary wording). Although I do like the note about using `.Cells` instead of `.Range` for the `Debug.Print` command. You could have saved yourself a lot of time by upvoting our answers and just adding that `Debug.Print` suggestion in the comments. Since you called me out, I'll change my down-vote to an up-vote for the time you spent, but you have to edit it first (S.O. won't let me change it until you do). I suggest adding references to the previous answers.

Comment: I started writing the answer a couple of hours before I posted it, presumably just before you posted yours which I didn't see at the time. I had a few interruptions in between which is why it took so long. ARich's answer *didn't* address the issue of the property needing to be a string, yours did. Had I seen it before posting I would have acknowledged that. YOU may consider the wording unnecessary, I consider it the difference between giving a man a fish and teaching him how. It certainly won't do him any HARM to know how to validate the input and that ranges don't return single values.

Comment: And incidentally, even if I HAD seen your reply you, and indeed nobody else, had mentioned to that point that Worksheets(Aux).Range("B1:B" & n_users).Value is invalid for multi-cell ranges which I did in my "unnecessary" code comments; it would get you a type mismatch. So sorry for "unnecessarily" bringing that up as well. Between this kind of thing and people who ask questions and don't even acknowledge the answers (which is what happened with my previous two answers) it's hardly surprising that people walk away from this site.

Comment: Dearest Alan, first of all, I stepped forward as you suggested and even offered to give you an up-vote, so let's not get snippy :) Second, I explained my answer's reasoning and provided reference material, but unlike you I managed to stick to the topic. Are you insinuating that I did not teach this man to fish? I would say I taught him how to fish while you taught him how to build a boat. **Edit** I believe I commended your `Range.Value` contribution in my first comment.